# How to debug Kotlin applications running in Kubernetes pods in IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, kotlin, kubernetes, remote-debugging

I'm successfully debugging Spring Boot applications written in Java inside Kubernetes using the following setup:

- Add `-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:5005"` to the `mvn spring-boot:run` command line in `Dockerfile`.
- Add

  ```
  - name: java-debug
    containerPort: 5005
  ```

  to `spec.containers.ports` of the `Deployment` and

  ```
  - name: java-debug
    protocol: TCP
    port: 5005
    targetPort: 5005
  ```

  to `spec.ports` of the `Service`.
- Add a `Remote` run configuration with `Debugger mode` set to `Attach to remove JVM` and the host of the `Service`.

Doing the same for a Kotlin project, the debugger connects to the JVM and accepts breakpoints, however, doesn't stop at them, no matter how often I execute the code where it should stop. The code is executed on k8s according to logs and application feedback.

I'm testing this locally on microk8s using IntelliJ 2019.1.2 CE.

Comment: (a) your story sounds suspiciously like debugging in production -- why not run the application on your machine like a normal developer? (b) you didn't specify what kind of `Service` you have, as -- by default -- the Service's IP is only meaningful inside the cluster

Comment: I have the exact same problem right now. Did you manage to find a solution to it?

Comment: @DaltreyWaters Not this exact problem, but I added mdaniels note as an answer because that's the right approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mdaniel noted, it's indeed a sign of bad practices if I need to do what I'm trying to do. This task needs to be approached with configurable logging and integration tests.